# How do I save a small file I just modified in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using the following code to grab and modify my file. I console.log it and it works. However, I do not know how to save the modified file. These are very small files, is there a quick way to save it once I read it and update it?

```
User.findOne({
            name : userName
        }, function(error, result) {
            result.points -= point;
            result.negative += negative;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to update an existing document, then [the `update` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) is the way to go. In the example you posted the [`$inc` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)  would be useful:

```
User.update({name: userName}, {
  $inc: {
    points: -point,
    negative: negative
  }
});
```

Comment: Do I use the code you wrote, or do I also include the code I wrote as well? I ask because I have tried both and I have something wrong.

Comment: No error, it is simply not updating my file. When I use my code above, and console log it - it shows the adjustments. But it doesn't save it. When I use your code, I am not sure how to console log it but it does not save the changes when I log into the user and check the score.